# Parsing XML using Python ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an XML document in the following format

```
<root>
<H D="14/11/2017">
<FC>
    <F LV="0">The quick</F>
    <F LV="1">brown</F>
    <F LV="2">fox</F>
</FC>
</H>
<H D="14/11/2017">
<FC>
    <F LV="0">The lazy</F>
    <F LV="1">fox</F>
</FC>
</H>
</root>
```

How can I extract the text from 'D' inside H tag and also all the text inside the F tags.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [ElementTree docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

> We can import this data by reading from a file:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

> Or directly from a string:

```
root = ET.fromstring(country_data_as_string)
```

and later in the same page, 20.5.1.4. Finding interesting elements:

```
for neighbor in root.iter('neighbor'):
    print(neighbor.attrib)
```

Which translate to:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring("""
<root>
<H D="14/11/2017">
<FC>
    <F LV="0">The quick</F>
    <F LV="1">brown</F>
    <F LV="2">fox</F>
</FC>
</H>
<H D="14/11/2017">
<FC>
    <F LV="0">The lazy</F>
    <F LV="1">fox</F>
</FC>
</H>
</root>""")
# root = tree.getroot()
for h in root.iter("H"):
    print (h.attrib["D"])
for f in root.iter("F"):
    print (f.attrib, f.text)
```

output:

```
14/11/2017
14/11/2017
{'LV': '0'} The quick
{'LV': '1'} brown
{'LV': '2'} fox
{'LV': '0'} The lazy
{'LV': '1'} fox
```

Answer (score 4):

You did not specifiy what exactly you whant to use so i recommend *lxml* for python. For getting the values you whant you have more possibiltys:

**With a loop:**

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse('XmlTest.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
text = []
for element in root:
   text.append(element.get('D',None))
     for child in element:
       for grandchild in child:
         text.append(grandchild.text)
print(text)
```

Output: 
['14/11/2017', 'The quick', 'brown', 'fox', '14/11/2017', 'The lazy', 'fox']

**With xpath:**

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse('XmlTest.xml')
root = tree.getroot() 
D = root.xpath("./H")
F = root.xpath(".//F")

for each in D:
  print(each.get('D',None))

for each in F:
  print(each.text)
```

Output:
14/11/2017
14/11/2017
The quick
brown
fox
The lazy
fox

Both have there own advantages but give you a good starting point.
I recommend the [xpath](http://lxml.de/3.0/tutorial.html) since it gives you more freedom when values are 
missing.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
data='''
<root>
<H D="14/11/2017">
<FC>
    <F LV="0">The quick</F>
    <F LV="1">brown</F>
    <F LV="2">fox</F>
</FC>
</H>
<H D="14/11/2017">
<FC>
    <F LV="0">The lazy</F>
    <F LV="1">fox</F>
</FC>
</H>
</root>
'''
#list created to store data
D_data=[]
F_data=[]

#data parsed
root= ET.XML(data)

#This will get the value of D
for sub in root:
    b=(sub.attrib.get('D'))
    D_data.append(b)

#This will get all the text for F tag in xml
for f in root.iter("F"):
    b=f.text
    #print f.tag,f.attrib,f.text
    F_data.append(b)

print D_data
print F_data
```