# How to search through a paragraph of text for a list of words, and once found, add to a dictionary

Tags: python

I am using a GET request to receive XML information back from a website.  I have parsed the information and have gotten a point where I want to set up a new scenario.

The Scenario is, when I run a FOR loop through the xml(now turned into text in a dictionary []) how can I:

1. search the whole text for a variety of words?  For example, say I know I'm looking for "value", "Lastupdatedate", and "Createdby" and want to grab that information everytime I see it
2. IF I find one of those words above, grab the word, and everything in between them (this is xml, so if I find "value"  I want to grab the information in between like (value - 5 - value) ?.  So the final information would have value: 5

`finalvalues = []`

```
MASTER = [This is the text I'm searching through]
```

`variables = ["value", "Lastupdatedate", "Createdby"]`

`for i in MASTER:
    #need something here to grab the actual name that it found
    tst = re.findall(variables(.*?)variables,i)
    finalvalues.append(tst)`

Comment: Based on your question, is there a reason you want to work with the XML as a single text string, rather than parsing it and getting the data contained in the tags, as in [this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47280129/parsing-xml-using-python-elementtree)

Comment: To clarify, are you looking for how to get all of the words between any two elements in `variables`, given an string of words? And what is your desired output? A list of all of the strings that are between your variables? There are a few details in your question that I'm not sure are relevant to what you are asking help for.

Comment: @G.Anderson You were right, I am now using ElementTree to parse through the XML.  Way easier (best way to learn is to jump head first).  I was able to figure it out.  Sorry for not responding sooner